# Error in Hbase and pig. ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I am running the following command on my machine: `pig -x local -f Hbase/load_hbase.pig`

Here's the Pig Stack Trace I'm getting, hopefully for the better understand my problem.

```
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:635)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1296)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1284)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.func_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:5158)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.store_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:7756)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1669)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1678)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1411)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:344)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:369)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:355)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:478)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.WritableByteArrayComparable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 28 more
```

Here is the code I'm running

```
raw_data = LOAD '/data/QCLCD201211/201211hourly.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
weather_data = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE $1, $10;
ranked_data = RANK weather_data;
final_data = FILTER ranked_data BY $0 IS NOT NULL;
STORE final_data INTO 'hbase://weather' 
         USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('info:date info:temp');
```

As you can see, I think the error code is not in the pig but something else that I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

copy pig jar and hbase jar in hadoop

1) COPY THESE FILES TO THE HADOOP LIBRARY.

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/pig/lib/pig-common-0.8.0-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
sudo cp /usr/lib/pig/lib/hbase-0.96.2-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
sudo cp /usr/lib/pig/lib/hbase-0.96.2-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
```

2)CLOSE HBASE AND HADOOP USING FOLLOWING COMMOND

```
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
/usr/lib/hbase/bin/stop-hbase.sh
```

3) RESTART HBASE AND HADOOP USING COMMOND

```
 /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-hbase.sh
```